# iOS 13 reminders app url scheme does not work

Tags: ios, url-scheme, ios13, reminders

After iOS 13 update the url scheme for reminders app `x-apple-reminder://` does not work anymore.

```c
        NSString *url = @"x-apple-reminder://";
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
```

How can I find the new url scheme? I searched on the web,but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new url for the reminders app in `iOS13` is `x-apple-reminderkit://`.